# How to add bridging header to Flutter Plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods, podspec

I'm trying to create Flutter plugin, which uses Swift and has one pod dependency (`NearbyMessages`)

First of all, I've added it to `.podspec`

```
#
# To learn more about a Podspec see http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html
#
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'flutter_nearby_messages'
  s.version          = '0.0.1'
  s.summary          = 'A new flutter plugin project.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
A new flutter plugin project.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'email@example.com' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.public_header_files = 'Classes/**/*.h'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'
  //************ I've added this lines ***************
  s.dependency 'NearbyMessages' 
  s.xcconfig = { 'SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER' => 'Classes/bridging_header.h' }
  //********* ^^ I've added this lines ^^ ************
  s.static_framework = true
  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
end
```

After pod install and initial empty project built, everything seems to be fine

I've tried using it in Objective-C:

```
#import "FlutterNearbyMessagesPlugin.h"
#import <NearbyMessages/GNSMessages.h>
#import <flutter_nearby_messages/flutter_nearby_messages-Swift.h>

@implementation FlutterNearbyMessagesPlugin
+ (void)registerWithRegistrar:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistrar>*)registrar {    
    GNSMessageManager *messageManager =
    [[GNSMessageManager alloc] initWithAPIKey:@"API_KEY"];
  [SwiftFlutterNearbyMessagesPlugin registerWithRegistrar:registrar];
}
@end
```

And it works, but when I try:

```
public class SwiftFlutterNearbyMessagesPlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
    private var client: GNSMessageManager? = nil
```

XCode says `Use of undeclared type GNSMessageManager`

I understand, that I need bridging header, and I've already tried to creating it, but it seems not to be linked at all.

Bridging header contains just one line: `#import <NearbyMessages/GNSMessages.h>`

So my question is, how to add bridging header to flutter plugin?

Comment: Can you show the contents of the bridging header file? Have you imported GNSMessageManager in the file?

Comment: @AndreiDurnea bridging header contains just one line `#import <NearbyMessages/GNSMessages.h>`

Comment: Did you `import NearbyMessages` in your Swift file?

Comment: No, I do not. I know though, that everyone makes stupid and simple mistakes from time to time - we are only human. And that part was not in your Swift code sample, while it was in your Obj-C code sample. I was just trying to get the obvious out of the way. I'm sorry if it came through as offending.

Comment: Wasted 150 rep bounty on this, great

Comment: I am interesed and knowing how to do this also, you found any solution?

Comment: @DanielOliveira yeah, I've found pretty hacky solution, it works locally but I'm afraid to publish it to pub. Take a look at this repo https://github.com/rostopira/flutter_nearby_messages and this file  https://github.com/rostopira/flutter_nearby_messages/blob/master/ios/Classes/NearbyMessages/module.modulemap

Comment: @DanielOliveira problem is actually in dependency pod, they don't have `.modulemap`. If you can contact developers of required dependency, ask them to add it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only solution that worked for me for adding a Bridging Header file to a Flutter plugin was putting the header file in `Classes` folder and then adding this to `.podspec`:

```
s.public_header_files = 'Classes/**/*.h'
```