# How to add bridging header in Flutter Plugin?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, flutter-plugin

I am trying to add an Obj C cocoapod into my Swift plugin.

However there isn't any bridging header file that flutter auto-generates when I make a new plugin with `-i swift`.

I tried adding it in my `.h` file but that didn't seem to work in my case.

I get the following error:

> Include of non-modular header inside framework module

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://medium.com/@florentmorin/integrating-swift-framework-with-non-modular-libraries-d18098049e18

Comment: @grow4gaurav my file is already public as it is a dependency on Cocoapods, however I don't know how do I add an Obj-c header file in a swift flutter plugin?

Comment: [This duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52932436/how-to-add-bridging-header-to-flutter-plugin) may be useful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add bridging header to Flutter Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52932436/how-to-add-bridging-header-to-flutter-plugin)